# How to check if a project is built using Swift or Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How can I figure out from within a framework I built, if projects that integrated this framework use Swift or Objective C?

Comment: A project may use both Swift and Objective-C. Are you trying to figure out if a particular source file including a header is Swift/Objective-C?

Comment: Yes, This could be the case. My question is, how can i figure out if the project is build with swift/objective c, or in the case where they are both used, which is the leading language, for example, if the AppDelegate will be .swift or .h/.m.

Comment: Why should it matter at runtime?

Comment: It should be in runtime because the framework is already compiled when the developer add it to his project.

Comment: Just for research...
You have any other way to know if the project was originally created in swift/objective c ?